# XB must be a 2-dimensional array in cdist

Tags: python, arrays, euclidean-distance

I have two 3D array as

```
clusters = [array([[ 0.42199652, -0.14364404,  0.21290469]]), 
   array([[  5.80084178e-05,   1.20779787e-02,  -2.65970238e-02],
   [ -1.36810406e-02,   6.85722519e-02,  -2.60280724e-01],
   [  3.03098198e-02,   1.50170659e-02,  -1.09683402e-01],
   [ -1.50776089e-03,   7.22369575e-03,  -3.71181228e-02],
   [ -3.04448275e-01,  -3.66987035e-01,   1.44618682e-01],
   [  1.16567762e-03,   1.72858807e-02,  -9.39297514e-02],
   [  1.25896836e-04,   1.61310167e-02,  -6.00253128e-02],
   [  1.65062798e-02,   1.96933143e-02,  -4.26540031e-02],
   [ -3.78020965e-03,   7.51770012e-03,  -3.67852984e-02]]), 
   array([[-0.14674492,  0.34711217,  0.30955027]])

out_list = [[ 0.01650628  0.01969331 -0.042654  ]
   [-0.00150776  0.0072237  -0.03711812]
   [ 0.0001259   0.01613102 -0.06002531]]
```

I have to find out euclidean distance between each row of the `out_list` to each array in `clusters`
I have some code as

```
intra_dist = [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(clusters[i],out_list[i], 'euclidean') for i in xrange(num_clusters)]
```

but it gives me `ValueError: XB must be a 2-dimensional array.`
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write embedding1, embedding2 without index positions

## Find the closest 5 sentences of the corpus for each query sentence based on cosine similarity

```
closest_n = 5
for query, query_embedding in zip(headlines, headline_embeddings):
    distances = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(embedding1, embedding2, "cosine")[0]

    results = zip(range(len(distances)), distances)
    results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `out_list` is 1-dimensional array of `numpy` list. Notice that there is no comma between values `out_list`, but in clusters there is a comma between values. To make it work it is necessary to convert  `out_list` in a 2-dimensional list:

```
    out_list_new = []
    for element in (out_list):
       out_list_new.append([element[0], element[1])

   intra_dist = [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(clusters[i],out_list[i], 'euclidean') for i in xrange(num_clusters)]
```

should work